jQuery find a li element within ul
I've a function, which should remove a li element from a list identified by the id.
I use jQuery and this call
$("#selector").find("li[id='" + id.substring(4) + "']").remove();

The call started with a click on a button.
In Firefox it works without problems ... in Chrome not.
Has anyone an idea why?

Have you tried another attribute? I can imagine Chrome not working the id like any other attribute since there already is the # selector for it.

Are you trying to do a partial match on ID? Otherwise,, there's no reason to use an attribute selector (or find) to get the element. IDs must be unique to the document, so you can just do ${`#${id.substring(4)}`).remove(); and, if there's an element with an id the same as id.substring(4), it will get removed (barring special characters as indicated by the answer).

The issue might be due to differences in how Chrome and Firefox handle certain JavaScript/jQuery functionalities. Try the following:
1 : Ensure id.substring(4) returns the correct value. Use console.log(id.substring(4)) to verify.
2: Escape special characters in the ID:
var safeId = id.substring(4).replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1");
$("#selector").find("li[id='" + safeId + "']").remove();

3 : Wrap the removal code in a setTimeout to handle reflow issues:
setTimeout(function()
 {`enter code here`
    $("#selector").find("li[id='" + safeId + "']").remove();
}, 0);


You can use the CSS.escape function instead of rolling your own...
